# Image in circle above text div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to place an image in a circle div that's placed above a section containing text like in the image shown:[image]

How can this be done using CSS? Thank you.

Comment: please add your code what you try..

Comment: yes please add some code

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor The only problem is that I can't move the circle above the text div

Comment: No, your code needs to go in your question in a [mcve] not a third party side. Codepen could be down, blocked, sold, or disappear for a variety of reasons, at which point your question becomes useless to visitors.

Comment: @j08691 Indeed, but as I couldn't find a plausible (or even close) solution by myself, I decided not to add any code in the question. I considered the codepen as an accessory of what I was trying to do.

Comment: @RobertFedus you accept the answer but your picture show different things ...

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I tried his code and it worked for me exactly as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Run the Code Here
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHOLRSYI9PEK

```css
 .flex-wrapper{
      background-color: lightgray;
      padding: 30px;
      padding: 30px 30px 30px 100px;
    }
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .flex-container{
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .avatar-wrapper{
    min-width: 150px;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -50px !important;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 150px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .avatar-wrapper:after{
        content: '';
        height: calc(100% + 40px);
        width: calc(100% + 40px);
        position: absolute;
        background: purple;
        top: -20px;
        left: -20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    
    .avatar-wrapper > img{
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="flex-wrapper">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="col avatar-wrapper">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="sample">
        </div>
        <div class="col text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
img{ border-radius:50%; z-index:1 }

.container{
  z-index:0;
  margin-left:-100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px lightgrey;
  padding:5px;
  width:50%;
  }
  
.text{
  text-decoration:underline blue;
  margin-left:100px;
  }
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250">
<div class="container">
<div class="text">
I'm trying to place an image in a circle div that's placed above a section containing text like in the image shown:
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is your solution. Just add your Image url in img tag